# Limit of iterated midpoint polygons

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Consider an arbitrary polygon $p$, and then take its midpoint polygon $p'$.  Repeat this process to create $p''$, $p'''$, etc.  Is there always a convex polygon in this series?

Answer (score 1):

See the MO question, "['Derived'  polyhedra and polytopes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/149770/6094)."
See especially [the answer by Gjergji Zaimi](https://mathoverflow.net/a/149855/6094), who says:

> "the limiting shape ... is in fact the affine image of a regular $n$-gon"

---

[image: DerivedPolygons3x5]

---